# Exception with type System:Char

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, app.xaml

I am trying to create a reusable `System:Char` value in my `xaml` resources.

I have:

```
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Then:

```
<s:Char x:Key="MaskPromptChar">#</s:Char>
```

I get an exception:

```
The type 'Char' was not found. [Line: 8 Position: 44]
```

But... I also have:

```
<s:Double x:Key="DefaultControlWidth">200</s:Double>
```

And...

```
<s:String x:Key="ApplicationTitle">My Title</s:String>
```

Both `String` and `Double` work fine.

Ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me in both Silverlight and WPF.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<sys:Double x:Key='myDouble'>4</sys:Double>
<sys:Char  x:Key='myChar'>#</sys:Char>
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
  <PasswordBox Password='aaa'
               PasswordChar='$' />
  <PasswordBox Password='aaa'
               PasswordChar='{StaticResource myChar}' />
</StackPanel>
```

What property are you trying to assign the char to?

Comment: I am assigning it to a 3rd party control's property. Currently, right now I am not assigning it to anything, just defining it in xaml. At runtime it complains with `The type 'Char' was not found. [Line: 8 Position: 44]`

Comment: Did you name any of your types in your project named Char? That could cause a name conflict.

Comment: No I didn't name any type Char anywhere.

Comment: At this point I'm not sure what to say.  The XAML works on my computer, but is failing on yours.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that [Char is a structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), rather than an object, and what's you're really looking at is boxing of a 16-bit integer value representing Unicode.  I tend to look at XAML as a specialization serialization of *objects*, and if Char is actually a [struct](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2007/07/struct-vs-class-in-net.html), this model may break down.

You might want to consider biting the bullet and using a String of length one instead.

**UPDATE**: I agree with gmcalab's solid line of reasoning, and based on that conducted an experiment using a namespace to mscorlib and the corresponding character resource.  **It worked** without a hitch.  (Are we now looking at a namespace or library collision problem?)

Comment: I tried to use a `string` with Length of one but when I go to use the Key it won't convert the type `string` to type `char`. i.e. `PromptChar='{StaticResource MyStringLengthOfOne}'` gives me an exception `Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Char'.`

Comment: I was just suggesting using the My Title example and keeping it a String throughout the whole app.  Perhaps not ideal for your masking case, though.

Comment: @Walt, yes I know that's what you were suggesting, but the control property expects a `char`, therefore using a `string` with a length of 1 will not work, hence the exception in my previous comment.

Comment: @Walt, in response to your UPDATE... what worked? You don't provide any code to show us.

Comment: Your example of `<sys:Char x:Key='myChar'>#</sys:Char>` worked just fine in my XMAL file.  I just did what you did.

Comment: What is your namespace declaration for `sys`

Comment: Oh my. Two Walts on one thread. I think you are talking with Walt Stoneburner, but here's my namespace declaration. 
 xmlns:sys='clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib'

Comment: `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`